# this code prints nothing on intelliJ idea, it didn't even takes user input or anything

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Write your code here.
            // Read integer
            int integer = scan.nextInt();

            // Read double
            double doubleValue = scan.nextDouble();

            // Read string
            scan.nextLine();
            String string = scan.nextLine();

            // Print the results
            System.out.println("String: " + string);
            System.out.println("Double: " + doubleValue);
            System.out.println("Int: " + integer);
        }
    }
```

It's a hackerrank problem and the hackerrank compiler says it's correct. I solved the problem but I want to know why IntelliJ IDEA prints nothing in this code (note : All the code I have written before in IntelliJ runs perfectly except this)

Comment: Obviously, this code won't output anything if you don't enter a single character into a running console.

Comment: means could you explain it in a more detailed way please!

Comment: Of course I wrote the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you run that code in Intellij IDEA the following happens:

- The `Scanner` is assigned to the "standard" input stream corresponding to the keyboard input:

  ```java
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  ```
- Scans the next token from the input, if there is no input, the scanner will wait for this to happen:

  ```java
  int integer = scan.nextInt();
  ```
- The same behaviour for `double` and `string`:

  ```java
  double doubleValue = scan.nextDouble();
  scan.nextLine(); // there is "empty" scan for String to avoid https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/22270964
  String string = scan.nextLine();
  ```
- After all scans the code will print results:

  ```java
  System.out.println("String: " + string);
  System.out.println("Double: " + doubleValue);
  System.out.println("Int: " + integer);
  ```

So if you run the program and don't type **3 times (2 lines)**, you won't see any results.

For example, there is my console where I have to type to see some results:
[image]